Complex algebraic equation with branch cut
I want to identify the location of the solutions to the following equation on different Riemann sheets of the square root:
$$
(z+ i) \sqrt{1+z^2}=z \quad \quad\quad\quad(1)
$$
If we go around the branch cut, then the square root obtain minus sign in front, so one the second Riemann sheet, the above equation is written in the following form:
$$
-(z+ i) \sqrt{1+z^2}=z \quad \quad\quad\quad(2)
$$
One finds the fourth-order polynomial equation by squaring both sides of the equation (1). The equation's discriminant tells you that there are two imaginary solutions and two complex solutions:
$$
z\in \{i x, -i x , z_1 , z_2 \}, \quad x>0
$$
By inserting the first two solutions to the equation (1), you will find the following relations:
$$
\sqrt{(1-x)(1+x)} = \frac{x}{x+1},\quad \sqrt{(1-x)(1+x)} = \frac{x}{x-1}
$$
We observe that the second relation is contradictory, so $-i x$ is not a solution to Equation (1). However, if we substitute these solutions into Equation (2), then $-i x$ is indeed a solution. This indicates that $i x$ belongs to the first Riemann sheet, while $-i x$ belongs to the second Riemann sheet.
Now the question is how to determine whether the third and fourth solutions belongs to the first or second Riemann sheet ?
Since the explicit forms of the solutions are quite complex (as they are solutions to a fourth-order polynomial), I am unsure of the best way to determine this.
Any help would be much appreciated.

I have the feeling that squaring introduces an extra root and that the equation is in fact a cubic with one pure imaginary solution.
